# Compare list data to readline input

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, if-statement, foreach

i am reading a txt file to an array and then taking the data from the array and putting it in to a custom type list.

```
var StylistFile = File.ReadLines("stylist.txt").ToArray();
var lineCount = File.ReadLines("stylist.txt").Count();

int k = (lineCount) / 6; // used tocalculates number of stylists by looking at the number of lines
int L = 1;

List <Stylist> stylists = new List<Stylist>();


for (L = 1;L <=k; L++) 
{

    string[] stylistsL = new string[6];
    Stylist stylistL = new Stylist();
    stylists.Add(stylistL);

    foreach (var i in stylists) 
    {
        stylistL.FirstName = StylistFile[((L - 1) * 6) + 0];
        stylistL.LastName = StylistFile[((L - 1) * 6) + 1];
        stylistL.Email = StylistFile[((L - 1) * 6) + 2];
        stylistL.Phone = StylistFile[((L - 1) * 6) + 3];
        stylistL.Rate = StylistFile[((L - 1) * 6) + 4];

        stylistsL[0] = stylistL.FirstName;
        stylistsL[1] = stylistL.LastName;
        stylistsL[2] = stylistL.Email;
        stylistsL[3] = stylistL.Phone;
        stylistsL[4] = stylistL.Rate;
        stylistsL[5] = "";
    }
}
foreach (var i in stylists) // prints the stylists first and last names
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.FirstName + " " + i.LastName);
}

string stylistSelected = Console.ReadLine();

//foreach (var z in stylists) // goes through each stylist in list
for (int z = 0; z <= stylists.Count; z++)
{

    if ((stylistSelected == stylists[z].FirstName) || (stylistSelected == stylists[z].FirstName + " " + stylists[z].LastName)) // checks to see if stylistSelected match current stylists
    {
       Console.WriteLine(stylists[z].FirstName + " " + stylists[z].LastName);
```

the custom class code is

```
public class Stylist 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Rate { get; set; }
}
```

the txt file is formatted like so

```
john
smith
js@123.456
123456789
123

jane
doe
jd@123.456
987654321
1456
```

i am able to get the code to print each item within the list but i can't find a way to get the code to check the data in the list against the a readline string how do i go about doing this?

i have tried using both `foreach` and a `for` loop. i have tried using a new int variables for both the `for` and `foreach` loop

a second question is, can i have it so `stylistL`, becomes `stylist1`, `stylist2`, ... and so on, so that it scales with the data with the txtx file?

Comment: You don't need to `ReadLines` twice. `lineCount = StylistFile.Length;`

Comment: What is the point of `string[] stylistsL = new string[6];`? You create one on every iteration, assign some values, and then it's thrown away when the `foreach` loop ends.

Comment: @RufusL i thought that as the txt file has 5 pieces of data and followed by a space for each stylist, i would need to create an array of size six to make it easier for my to call back for the data later on in the code

Comment: what does "check the data" actually mean? What do you mean by `stylist1`, `stylist2`, ...?

Comment: If you meant to reference the array of six `string`s later, why do you overwrite its members each time through the wasted loop? And why do you need it and an object of type `Stylist` both?

Answer (score 0):

To populate a `List<Stylist>` from your text file, we can do something like the following, where we read the file into an array (ignoring any blank lines), then set a loop counter to increment by `5` on each iteration (since every 5 lines represents a Stylist), and inside the loop we set the properties of a new `Stylist` and add it to our `List<Stylist>`.

The code below assumes every 5 lines represents a stylist (and it ignores any blank lines in the file):

```
var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(stylistFilePath)
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    .ToList();

var stylists = new List<Stylist>();

// We have a condition to exit the loop if 'i + 4 < fileLines.Count'
// because we attempt to access item [i + 4] inside the loop.
for (int i = 0; i + 4 < fileLines.Count; i += 5)
{
    stylists.Add(new Stylist
    {
        FirstName = fileLines[i],
        LastName = fileLines[i + 1],
        Email = fileLines[i + 2],
        Phone = fileLines[i + 3],
        Rate = fileLines[i + 4]
    });
}
```